# How to reset a class instance in python?

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, instance

I am trying to return the fibonacci numbers but it prints 2 instead of 1 after calling start.next().next(). How can I solve this issue?

```
class Fib():

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0



    def next(self):

        if self.value == 0:
            self.total = 1
            self.previous = 0
            self.value = 1

        else:
            print(self.previous)
            self.value = self.total + self.previous
            hold = self.total
            self.previous, self.total = hold, self.value


        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

Comment: Can you show how you intend to use a Fib object?

Comment: start = Fib() , and then calling on start would return "0", calling start.next() would return "1", calling start.next().next() would return "1", and so on in a fibonacci sequence

Comment: `start.next().next().next().next().next().next().next()` prints a coherent sequence if you assume the first `next` call to begin at index 0.

Comment: what do you mean by "begin at index 0"?

Comment: fib(0) = 0, fib(1) = 1, fib(2) = 1, fib(3) = 2, fib(4) = 3, fib(5) = 5